# Background thread saving a file and accessing that file in the main thread causing a crash

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a background thread that's downloading a file from a server and then storing that file to disk. Once that process is done, it calls a callback function running on the main thread. That callback function essentially opens the file using `std::ifstream`. I do get some nasty crashes occasionally, which while hard to decipher

```
0x00007ffa054901f9 in MSVCP140!?seekg@?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@V?$fpos@U_Mbstatet@@@2@@Z ()
   from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msvcp140.dll
```

indicates that there's a problem. When I load a file from the server for the first time it works. It's only when I follow that by another download that the problem occurs.

Here is the original code:

```
void DownloadFile(const uint32_t& id, std::function<void(std::string)> 
    auto file = files_[id];
    std::string file_path = cache_folder_loc_ + "/" + file->name;

    if (thread_.joinable())
        thread_.join();

    thread_ = std::thread([this, file, file_path, callback]{
        net::TcpClientSocket& tcp_client_socket = net::TcpClientSocket::Get();
        net::NetIOResult result =
            tcp_client_socket.PerformRequest(
                net::RequestType::DownloadFile,
                download_info_.progress, file->name);
        if (result.error.has_value()) {
            std::cerr << "Error: Failed downloading " << file->name
                << " (" << result.error.value() << ")" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        const net::Blob& blob = std::get<net::Blob>(result.data.value());
        std::ofstream ofs;
        std::string file_dst = cache_folder_loc_ + "/" + file->name;
        ofs.open(file_dst.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
        ofs.write((char*)blob.data(), blob.size());
        assert(ofs.good());
        ofs.close();
        download_info_.download_in_progress = false;
        file->cached.store(true);
        callback(file_path);
    });

}
```

Then the callback:

```
void OnDoubleClick(int file_id) override {
    model_->DownloadFile(file_id, [this](std::string file_path) { this->OnDoubleClickCallback(file_path); });
}

void OnDoubleClickCallback(std::string file_path) {
    for (auto& observer : observers_)
        observer(file_path); // DataModel::Reload(file_path)
}
```

The observer

```
class DataModel {
    std::unique_ptr<Reader> reader_;
public:
    void Reload(const std::string& file_path) {
        reader_.reset(new Reader({file_path}));
    }
};

Reader::Reader(std::vector<std::string> file_paths) {
    for (const auto& file_path : file_paths) {
        std::ifstream* ifs = new std::ifstream(file_path, std::ios::binary);
        assert(ifs->good());
        streams_.push_back(ifs);
    }

    Factory factory;
    Factory::CoreType type;

    archive_ = factory.getArchive(streams_, type);
}
```

The `factory.getArchive()` is where the crashes occurs. It read the content of the file and excptions coming from `std::ifsteam` are raised.

If I use a promise/future in the thread and calling the callback method only when the future is fulfilled, like so:

```
std::promise<void> file_ready_promise;
std::future<void> file_ready_future = file_ready_promise.get_future();

thread_ = std::thread([this, file, callback, file_path, &file_ready_promise]{
    ...
    std::ofstream ofs;
    std::string file_dst = cache_folder_loc_ + "/" + file->name;
    ofs.open(file_dst.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
    ofs.write((char*)blob.data(), blob.size());
    ofs.close();
    ...
    file_ready_promise.set_value();
});

file_ready_future.get();
callback(file_path);
```

The problem is gone. But of course I don't want the main thread to be blocked because I need it to run to report progress on the download. It just shows that the issue is gone. I can also check that by running the download code in the main thread or have a `join()` right after the thread is called.

- For general knowledge, I'd like to know more about why this race condition occurs. It's my understanding that `ofstream::write` is synchronous, and so I would assume that the file is done writing when the callback is called when it's inside the thread. But obviously, that's not the case. Do caching issues cause that? I tried to put a `sleep_for` between the `close()` method and the call to the callback function (for diagnose purposes), but it doesn't make a difference. So it has more to do with the callback being called from another thread than caching, but my knowledge needs to be expanded to understand why? Any light shed on this would help me.
- How could I reliably implement this, so that the main thread keeps running while the bg thread downloads the file and get the callback function called when it's safe?

Comment: Not a solution, but a bit surprised at the `memory_order_relaxed` in the sync. Why? Also, I would check the result of a file open every single time. Not on Windows, but I have had cases where some other processes trying to create a duplicate file elsewhere in the cluster caused a temporary OS lock on "my" file, and the open timed out. Odd things can happen!

Comment: @BoP Thanks I will check the result but it seems like the files are good though. When I read them back in when no download is necessary, their content is valid. Regarding `memory_order_relaxed ` I guess specifying this is not needed if this is what you mean? file->cached is an `std::atomic<bool>` that can be accessed (write) by the download thread and the main thread (read).

Comment: It seems odd that you write to file `file->name.c_str()`, but read file `file_path`. Also, it's quite hard to make sense out of code you posted - I can see when you write to `file->cached`, but not when you read it... IMO there is not enough information here to tell the cause.

Comment: BTW, `memory_order_relaxed` doesn't  seem to be correct choice here - it only ensure atomicity of operation, but not order. On x86 it's probably not important, but in general you should use `memory_order_release` on store/`memory_order_acquire` on load. That what will enforce proper memory order. Or use something more high-level.

Comment: @MichaelNastenko I agree. I added the missing code.

Comment: A possible solution could be to use some IPC between the two threads. If allowed to use them, both [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) and or [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) open source libraries could be useful.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thx Basile. This is a summer R&D project for improving my C++ skills so while I can look at Qt and POCO for ideas/examples I can't use them for this project. Also IPC seems nice but it seems like looking at a rather complex solution for a problem that I would think could be solved in a simpler way? But I don't know the answer to that (obviously) so can't tell. Studying IPC seems like a big undertaking.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch very cool project. I will contact you.

Comment: There are too many questions in that code, please provide a [mcve]. Also, just one advise concerning multithreading: Document clearly which resources are shared and how access to them is synchronized. If possible, enforce synchronization programatically.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the main thread trying to access the content of the old archive while the background/download thread had deleted the old archive to replace it with the new one. So basically, the `ifstream` exception was related to the fact that the main thread was trying to read data from a stream that didn't exist anymore (or that it was in the middle of a read when the archive is deleted). Basic mistake.

How I solved the problem was to put an atomic bool around the code that creates the new archive (basically create a new `istream`). The main thread can't read data unless that boolean is set to false (`is_loading_new_file_`).

A special thanks for those who took the time to read and reply. Hints about `store(true, std::memory_order_release)` were useful.

### Edit:

In fact, wrong again. I had to use a `mutex` a `condition_variable` and an atomic boolean. When I read the data I acquire the lock, set the boolean to true before reading and to false after reading. In the method where I read a new file, I acquire the lock, set the condition so that it waits for the boolean to be false (not reading), then read the file, etc.

Comment: You probably don't need to use an atomic bool with a CV.  See https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-be-aware-of-the-traps-of-condition-variables/